# The jenkins job is not continue after checking the if statement

Tags: jenkins

```
stage('Checkout') 
    {
        steps
        {
            checkout scm
            script 
            {
                if (params.myParam == '') { // and/or whatever condition you want
                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                    error('myParam not set')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Above will Abort the build if parameter is null, working as expected.But when i give the value on parameter the job is still failing, not taking the value or passing the build.

Comment: Did you log the parameter before the `if` condition and check whether you have a value?

Answer (score 0):

The == '' (equality operator) also needs to be declared that it represents 'null' to satisfy the boolean value.

As this is not declared, any value in that parameter will meet the condition to error/false, see the slight change to your stage below:

```
stage('Checkout') {
  steps {
    checkout scm
    script {
      if(params.myParam == '' || params.myParam == null) {
        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
        error('myParam not set')
      } else {
          //whatever condition you want
      }
    }
  }
}
```